# Vertica REFRESH_COLUMNS fails with "Join inner did not fit in memory" error

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a inner join required for analytics between entities users, user_profiles and user_custom_profiles that results in a big wide entity with about 500 columns, the relation between those tables is 1 to 1.

I have then converted users in a flattened table where about 350 columns are created with **SET USING** getting the data from the other two tables. I haven't used **DEFAULT** because all those tables get updates everyday so those **SET USING columns** needs to be updated daily. The create statement for users table looks like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    user_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    tenant_id int NOT NULL,
    user_domain varchar(100) not null,
    import_file_id int DEFAULT NULL::int,
    target_id int DEFAULT NULL::int,
    customer_id varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    loyalty_id varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,+
    [...]
    -- columns from user_profiles table
    customer_base varchar(100) SET USING (
      select customer_base 
      from user_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_profiles.tenant_id 
        and users.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
        and users.user_domain = user_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    purchases int SET USING (
      select purchases 
      from user_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_profiles.tenant_id 
      and users.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
      and users.user_domain = user_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    customer_type INT SET USING (
      select customer_type 
      from user_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_profiles.tenant_id 
      and users.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
      and users.user_domain = user_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    [...]
    -- columns from user_custom_profiles table
    ucp_custom_11 VARCHAR(100) SET USING (
      select custom_11 
      from user_custom_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_custom_profiles.tenant_id 
      and users.user_id = user_custom_profiles.user_id 
      and users.user_domain = user_custom_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    ucp_custom_12 VARCHAR(100) SET USING (
      select custom_12 from user_custom_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_custom_profiles.tenant_id 
      and users.user_id = user_custom_profiles.user_id 
      and users.user_domain = user_custom_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    ucp_custom_13 VARCHAR(100) SET USING (
      select custom_13 from user_custom_profiles 
      where users.tenant_id = user_custom_profiles.tenant_id 
      and users.user_id = user_custom_profiles.user_id 
      and users.user_domain = user_custom_profiles.user_domain
    ),
    [...]
);
```

Till this point everything is okay, the problem is when I attempt to execute `SELECT REFRESH_COLUMNS('users_7', '', 'REBUILD');` to update all the columns seems that this function require huge amounts of memory and it fails with the following error:

```
SQL Error [3815] [53200]: [Vertica][VJDBC](3815) ROLLBACK: 
Join inner did not fit in memory [(public.users_super x public.user_custom_profiles) 
using previous join and subquery (PATH ID: 2)]
```

I have tested executing this with a few columns to be updated and works. But I would like to do it easier, I don't know what is Vertica doing in the background but seems is trying to load in memory the result of the join between users, user_profiles and user_custom_profiles in memory. I have created projections for the join between users and user_profiles and user_custom_profiles.

What really disconcerts me is that those tables have not much data, I have used the query provided here: [table-size](http://vertica.tips/2014/01/25/table-size/) to find out the compressed size of those tables and is not that big.

- users: 0.4 Gb (2.3 millions rows)
- user_profiles: 0.2 Gb (2.2 millions rows)
- user_custom_profiles: 0,01 Gb (2.2 millions rows)

I'm using Vertica CE 9.1 in a single node with 6 cores and 60 Gb RAM.

Is there a way to improve this function so will not use that much memory?

Answer (score 0):

Your join columns are always:

```
user_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
tenant_id int NOT NULL,
user_domain varchar(100) not null,
```

For this type of join, you will have to expect that all join columns will have to be materialised.

I expect a hash join for each of the 350 columns to be refreshed. Try to EXPLAIN a SELECT with one of those joins, and post it here ...

Even if VARCHARs can contain anything from zero bytes to the maximum possible length, Vertica does not know in advance how long each VARCHAR will be. So it will allocate a hash table for each of the 350 necessary joins using the maximum possible length for each row to be joined.

That would be:
350 joins * (100 bytes for user_id + 8 bytes for tenant_id + 100 bytes for user_domain) * 2.2 million rows.

If I do the maths correctly, that amounts to 160.160 GB of memory. That's almost 3 times as much as your single-noder has to offer.

My suggestions:

1. When and if-ever you can, avoid tables with hundreds of columns.
2. If you join tables often (and 350 derived columns is often enough), redesign your model to allow for equi-joins over integers. Either get a surrogate integer key using `HASH(user_id,tenant_id,user_domain)` (the hash collision risk is low enough to do that), or create a helper table for each of the 3 tables as I show below, and get the surrogate key into your 3 tables. Then, you can join using an equi-join over an INTEGER.
   You will need 8 bytes instead of 208 for each entry in your 350 hash tables for the joins.

Here's a design and population for your helper table:

```
CREATE TABLE helper(
  surrkey     IDENTITY
, user_id     VARCHAR(100) -- does it really have to be that big?
, tenant_id   INT
, user_domain VARCHAR(100)
)
ORDER BY user_id,tenant_id,user_domain,surrkey
SEGMENTED BY HASH(surrkey) ALL NODES;

INSERT /*+DIRECT */ INTO helper
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,tenant_id,user_domain FROM users;
```

In a nutshell: Independently of the DBMS: Never JOIN or GROUP BY columns that take considerably more than a dozen bytes if materialised if there is any way to avoid that. In a Vertica flattened tables context, in your case, 350 times so.

Comment: Also: how many percent of the 2.2 million rows are subject to updates daily? If it's more than 30%, you should replace the UPDATE approach by an intelligent CREATE-TABLE ... AS SELECT followed by an ALTER TABLE .. .RENAME TO ....